# Is there a parameter of `go build` to profile the Go's compiler itself?

Tags: go, compiler-construction

I want to know the time-consuming of different compilations stage of Go,e.g parse、type check、code gen.
in rust, rustc has a parameter "-Z self-profile" to profile itself,
[usage](https://github.com/rust-lang/measureme/blob/master/summarize/README.md)
I am wondering if there is a similar parameter to Go's compiler.

I found there is a go package, [parser](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser), which implements a parser for Go source files, using this package, I can (maybe) only measure time-consuming parsing.

Comment: Try to read more about this subject and then try to implement different solutions that you find. Then if you get stuck in any part of the code, put that piece of code here, with the problems you found.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a parameter of `go build` to profile the Go's compiler itself?

No.